# laravel stored how to check stored file

Tags: laravel, stored-procedures

I wrote some code to generate pdf file.

in my controller i have a code that look like that :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
class pdfGenerator extends Controller
{
public function show(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->json()->all();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('test2', compact('data'));
    $content = $pdf->download()->getOriginalContent();
    Storage::put('public/pdf/testPdf.pdf', $content);
        return $pdf->stream('testPdf',array("Attachment"=>0));

}
}
```

i traying to same file on my localhost but nothing work as expected.

i create folder in /public so path is /public/pdf/

but when i execute code nothing were saved on my local mahine.

So when code are generated i got output, i can check my pdf, but pdf in not saved on path.

it is path issue? or maybe because localhost?

**EDIT**

File were saved inside stored folder.

So i need to check the path to display IT, i tray somthing like that:
just after storedge function:

```
$url = Storage::url('public/pdf/testPdf.pdf');
print_r($url);
```

and i got : /storage/pdf/testPdf.pdf

So when i type: http://127.0.0.1:8001/storage/pdf/testPdf.pdf

404 not found.

Any clue?

Comment: You are not specifying a disk for the Storage, so it will use the default one. If you haven't changed it, it will store the file within the `/storage/app` directory. Have you checked to see if a file exists at `/storage/app/public`?

Comment: oo ye that right :D

Comment: George can you give me some clue? i already edit my question.

Comment: read up on laravel filesystems and the `config/filesystems.php`  file

Comment: @Piter I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the Storage disk so it is using Laravel's default value which is to store it within the `/storage/app` directory. This is not publicly available, but it can be made publicly available by running the command `php artisan storage:link` which will create a symlink. You can read more about this in the Laravel documentation.

Alternatively if you would like to store it within your public folder, specify that you would like to use the public disk.

```php
Storage::disk('public')->put('pdf/testPdf.pdf', $content);
```

Comment: so after that to generate a link i cna use that : $url = Storage::url('public/pdf/invoice.pdf'); ??  app is deploy on aws